# Problem with Celery task in Django, stopped for unknown reason

Tags: python, django, redis, gmail, django-celery

I made simple script using Django and Celery, which makes queries in Django database compares to dates with current date and send email. I use Heroku, and Redislab server for Resis server.

1. I used Celery beam and Celry worker to check every 1 second.
2. I made simple task which send emails from Gmail and the settings.py in Django.
   All fine.

When I deployed to Heroku it was working for few minutes,
then stoped.

What could be the possible reasons?
Is this the right approach?

What I think is: probably Gmail or the receiver mail told that that's flood.
Or...

Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: I hear your pain. I also experience sometimes that celery workers just get stuck and don't do anything anymore. There is also no logging in `celery.log` then anymore. Usually a restart of the workers helps. The problem is to detect when it's stuck. I use AWS SQS as a backing mechanism, so I now monitor the number of messages in the queue, although that is not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

There could a lot of reasons.

Add [Sentry](https://sentry.io/), as a logger. It will show you all errors in real-time. Probably you will fit in a free plan.